# Preserve browser history in Spotify app when links are clicked and javascript is manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, spotify, browser-history

Basically, I have written a Spotify app thats includes only a single page (index.html) with all the links triggering javascript `onclick()` functions that manipulate the DOM. For example, I show an initial 4 albums and have a "See More albums" link that loads and renders the rest of the albums. I did this so the initial 4 albums would only load once. I didn't realize there was a limitation on `pushState()`until I read the fine print. Spotify says you will get a "[security exception](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#integratingwiththespotifyapplicationshistory)" if you try to use `pushState()`. I prefer not re-writing the app to load new html pages on each link click. I tried their method of using the full URI (eg. `<a href='spotify:app:chirp:best_of:index'>`), but it behaves erratically ([code](https://github.com/chirpradio/chirpradio-spotify/blob/master/app/app.js#L124)). Recommendations on a general approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pushState` is not supported in Spotify apps. If you want to create a new entry in the history so that if the user clicks on the back button it returns to the previous state, then you should have a link like:

```html
<a href='spotify:app:chirp:best_of:2009'>See More</a>
```

And you would detect when the user has clicked by observing the `models.EVENT.ARGUMENTSCHANGED` event.

You can have a look at the [Spotify App Tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial) which uses a similar approach.

If you don't want to create a new entry, but just append some more albums, then there is no need to navigate to any new URI, then execute your `seeMoreAlbumsOfTheYearOnClick` function as currently.

Note that if you don't pretend to navigate to any new URL you should pass the event variable to your `seeMoreAlbumsOfTheYearOnClick` function and call `event.preventDefault();`. Another possibility is to use a `button` element instead.

Comment: Thanks! This helped immensely. I didn't realize these events were called when the back/forward buttons are clicked. It wasn't clear in the documentation that the arguments in the href get passed into the event observer